# Работа с разными данными на сайте через JSON в .NET

Tags: c#, json, .net

Загружаю с сайта через API данные
примеры:

```
#JSON
{
  "meta": {
    "model": "product", 
    "next": "", 
    "page": 1, 
    "previous": ""
  }, 
  "objects": [
    {
      "updated": "2013-10-24 11:08:53", 
      "description": "Some description about product", 
      "title": "\u041a\u0440\u0430\u0431", 
      "packing": "Packing deskription", 
      "article": "KR100AB", 
      "product_id": 1
    }, 
    {
      "updated": "2013-10-24 11:10:22", 
      "description": null, 
      "title": "Rezinka 100", 
      "packing": null, 
      "article": null, 
      "product_id": 2
    }
  ]
}`

и ещё пример:

 `{
  "meta": {
    "model": "price", 
    "next": "", 
    "page": 1, 
    "previous": ""
  }, 
  "objects": [
    {
      "discount": null, 
      "price": 10.75, 
      "updated": "2013-10-24 11:05:31", 
      "product_id": 1
    }, 
    {
      "discount": 25.0, 
      "price": 10.75, 
      "updated": "2013-10-24 11:05:37", 
      "product_id": 2
    }, 
    {
      "discount": 5.0, 
      "price": 10.75, 
      "updated": "2013-10-24 11:05:42", 
      "product_id": 3
    }
  ]
}`

Десериализируеться это в вот в такой набор классов:

`public class Meta
{
    public string model { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public string previous { get; set; }
}
public class Price
{
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string discount { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    public string article { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string packing { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
public class RootProduct
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public List<Product> objects { get; set; }
}
public class RootPrice
{
    public Meta meta {get;set;}
    public List<Price> objects {get;set;}
}
`
И Это только часть всего что нужно принять.
В общем это всё выходит в огромную структуру ветвление кода, т.к. пробами из запроса к сайту находиться каким классом нужно парсить JSON, потом это нужно запихнуть в datagridview.datasource.

`string JsonSouce = new  WebClient().DownloadString(textBoxAdress.Text);
textBoxJson.Text = JsonSouce.Replace("\n","\r\n");
try {
    var client = new RestClient(textBoxAdress.Text);
    var request = new RestRequest();

    if(JsonSouce.IndexOf("\"meta\":")>0)
        _jq = Json_qty.list;
    else
        _jq = Json_qty.item;
    if (textBoxAdress.Text.IndexOf("product")>0)
        _jt = Json_type.product;
    if (textBoxAdress.Text.IndexOf("price")>0)
        _jt = Json_type.price;
    switch (_jq) {
        case Form1.Json_qty.not:
            MessageBox.Show("Нет вхождения в нужные ветви по количеству JSON данных");
            break;
        case Form1.Json_qty.list:
            switch (_jt) {
                case Form1.Json_type.not:
                    MessageBox.Show("Нет вхождения в нужные ветви по типу JSON данных");
                    break;
                case Form1.Json_type.product:
                    var req_des11 = client.Execute<RootProduct>(request);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = req_des11.Data.objects;
                    break;
                case Form1.Json_type.price:
                    var req_des12 = client.Execute<RootPrice>(request);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = req_des12.Data.objects;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Invalid value for Json_type");
            }
            break;
        case Form1.Json_qty.item:
            switch (_jt) {
                case Form1.Json_type.not:
                    MessageBox.Show("Нет вхождения в нужные ветви по типу JSON данных");
                    break;
                case Form1.Json_type.product:
                    var req_des21 = client.Execute<Product>(request);
                    List<Product> _product = new List<Product>();
                    _product.Add(req_des21.Data);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = _product;
                    break;
                case Form1.Json_type.price:
                    var req_des22 = client.Execute<Price>(request);
                    List<Price> _price = new List<Price>();
                    _price.Add(req_des22.Data);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = _price;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Invalid value for Json_type");
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Invalid value for Json_qty");
    }
} catch{}
endregion
```

Дальше их нужно корректировать, но у меня уже не выходит без тупого ветвистого кода.
И я признаюсь что слабо понимаю как можно писать в такой ситуации правильно.
Как сделать универсальный массив который можно отображать в таблице и редактировать, а после даже выгружать?

Comment: Парсить JSON вручную не стоит, попробуйте любой из JSON-парсеров. Например, [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) или [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Тут не дело как парсить.
Я парсил через [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), Мне нужен способ JSON ответ распарсить в универсальный класс или объект, который можно подключать к dataGridView.DataSource . Чтобы редактировать, а после отправлять обратно.
Я в своем примере с помощью ветвления switch-ей могу распарсить в нужный класс и сразу в ветке подключить к таблице. Но когда я уже начинаю работать с таблицей не получается забрать класс обратно. кроме как работать с массивом ячеек, но мне нужно заново собрать JSON.
нашел [один вариант](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html#) курю его

Comment: юзайте JSON.NET, он позволяет производить сериализацию/десеарилизацию JSON в классы и обратно без этих танцев с бубном с поисками подстрок. И да, используйте MVC, MVP или MVVM, а то получается как у классика, когда  "смешались в кучу кони, люди"

Comment: Студия также умеет генерировать [классы из JSON ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx)

Comment: <Студия также умеет генерировать классы из JSON >
Был не в курсе, в основном люблю делать в SharpDevelop, ношу проекты и настроенный IDE с собой на флешке, периодически сохраняясь в GIT.

Comment: Нашел в общем способ который позволит загружать произвольный вариант JSON текст в таблицу, при этом дает возможность редактировать и добавлять.
[Вот решение](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589675/json-to-dataset-using-json-net)
Ну а запихивается как обычно 
    dataGridView2.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0]

Comment: @Михаил Николаевич, вы бы тогда опубликовали как ответ с деталями на русском, вдруг кому-то в будущем пригодится?

Comment: @VladD не хватает очков уважения(
Сам уже думал блог создать свой, т.к. много интересных и познавательных моментов по C# находил и решал.
У меня много проектов и в основном они боты и парсеры для работы с сайтами и данными. При чем начал программировать на C# с пару дневной подготовкой потому как нужно было по работе. Вот и до сих пор, я этим занимаю, плюс изучаю язык и его особенности, оптимизирую свой старый говнокод. Книг вообще не читал, Понравилась книга
[Rob Miles CSharp Yellow Book 2012](http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book), но хромает английский и русского варианта не нашёл.

Comment: @Михаил Николаевич, не в обиду вам будет сказано, но судя по вашему коду, а также тому, что вы "не читатель, а писатель", блог вам вести рановато